# ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero, how to print something then quit when users first enter a specific string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a homework that asked me to write a program that calculates the average of squares of a list.

So, if the program if okay, it will show :

> avgSumOfSquares()
>   Enter next number: 3.27
>   Enter next number: -1.9
>   Enter next number: 6
>   Enter next number: -1
>   Enter next number: end
>   The average of the sum of the squares is: 12.825725
>   12.825725
>   avgSumOfSquares()
>   Enter next number: end
>   No numbers were entered.

However, when I enter end, my program told me Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module> 
   avgSumOfSquares()  
File , line 34, in avgSumOfSquares  
   average = num_sum / amount  
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Here is my code

```
def avgSumOfSquares():
    input_list = []
    user_input = 0
    num_sum = 0             

    while user_input != "end":

        input_list.append(float(user_input))
        user_input = input("Enter next number :")

        squared = [i ** 2 for i in input_list]

        num_sum = sum(squared)
        amount = len(squared) - 1

        if len(input_list) == 0:
            print("No numbers were entered.")                     

        average = num_sum / amount

        print("The average of the sum of the squares is: ", average)
```

Comment: have you tried printing out the input list?  I think you'll be able to see why it's failing if you put a print statement in before calculating the average.

Comment: Not really related to your issue, but why are you dividing by `len(squared) - 1` instead of `len(squared)`?

Comment: Does it fail on the first try?

Comment: You can do `while True:` and then after user input, `if user_input=='end': break`. You would also have to move the appending to after the input.

Answer (score 1):

It is failing, because for the second number, `input_list` has length 1.  As a consequence, `ammount` will be 0.  You should put your average-checker in an `elif` block like this:

```
while user_input != "end":
    input_list.append(float(user_input))
    user_input = input("Enter next number :")

    if len(input_list) == 0:
        print("No numbers were entered.")
    elif len(input_list) > 1:
        squared = [i ** 2 for i in input_list]

        num_sum = sum(squared)
        amount = len(squared) - 1
        average = num_sum / amount

        print("The average of the sum of the squares is: ", average)
```

That should fix your problem, but I don't know why you define `ammount` as `len(squared) - 1`.  The average of 3 numbers is the sum of the 3 numbers divided by *3*, not 2.  If you were doing the average correctly, the `elif` could be `else` instead.

Comment: `sum(squared)` being zero has nothing to do with it: the issue is in the divisor (i.e., `amount`), not the dividend.

Comment: actually, it still shows wrong because the amount is zero if you enter end.

Comment: @WeizhengZhang: Are you referring to MarkDickinson's comment?

Comment: @zondo Actually,  I said to you because if I use your code it is still wrong.

Comment: @WeizhengZhang I have fixed my code so that it works on my computer.  When I posted my answer, I suppose it caused an error, because I didn't take into account that `ammount` is `len(squared) - 1` rather than `len(squared)` as it should be.  If it were `len(squared)`, then it would work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Because at first I give user_input 0, and I think 0 will be added into the list so the final amount should be minused 1. I am a little confused

Comment: In order to get the right average, we should delete -1

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get why you divide it to `len(squared) - 1` it should be `len(squared)` probably you might have thought end input but you do not add it input_list so no need.

```
def avgSumOfSquares():
    input_list = []
    num_sum = 0             
    user_input = input("Enter number :")
    while user_input != "end":
        input_list.append(float(user_input))
        user_input = input("Enter next number :")

    if len(input_list) == 0:
        print("No numbers were entered.")     
    else:
        squared = [i ** 2 for i in input_list]
        num_sum = sum(squared)
        amount = len(squared)               
        average = num_sum / amount
        print("The average of the sum of the squares is: ", average)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Because at first I give user_input 0, and I think 0 will be added into the list so the final amount should be minused 1. I am a little confused

Comment: Why do you have two user_input at the beginners ? One = 0 and another one is input

Comment: upps sorry l forgot to remove it.  `user_input=0` does not make any sense. because of that `len(input_list)` would never be equal to 0.